# Strange error return with sscanf

Tags: c, error-handling, scanf, cvi

I have this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int ret;
    int major =0, minor= 0, build =0, revision =0;
    char entry[16];
    strcpy(entry,"1.2");
    ret = sscanf(entry,"%d.%d.%d.%d", &major, &minor, &build, &revision);
    printf("sscanf(""%s"") returned %d\r\n", entry, ret);
    printf("major=%d, minor=%d, build=%d, revision=%d\r\n",
        major, minor, build, revision);
    return ret;
}
```

After `sscanf` is called, `ret` is -1, but first two entries are filled (major is 1, minor is 2).  I was expecting `ret` to be 2.  I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: What compiler are you using? For me it returns two (VC++ 2013)

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/bK9HKd

Comment: There is something that you are not saying.

Comment: Returns 2 on clang/macos.

Comment: Are you calling this in a `for` loop, does this exact code reproduce the behavior? is the version string `"1.2"` literal?

Comment: Not in a for loop. VS 2013. C code (not C++)

Comment: Version string is not a literal.  What I don't understand is why two values get filled in but return is -1.  Should be either ret of 2 or -1 (but no values get filled in).  Or maybe some other kind of error.

Comment: Possible that entry is "1.2 ".  Note space.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: @Jiminion Can you post the _full_ source code?

Comment: When the return value is `-1`, it is unspecified whether any of the output parameters have been changed.  Yet I do not understand why `sscanf` should return anything different than `2` in your example.

Comment: I need to interrogate errorno.  Something it doesn't like.

Comment: The same code did basically the same thing with two different compilers.  sscanf must not like something else about the input.  Thanks @chqrlie

Comment: OK, works in Vs 2013 code.  Does not work with CVI NI code.

Answer (score 1):

OK,  I think I figured out the problem.  The behavior is ok (it works) under VS 2013.  But the CVI Version (National Instruments) simply doesn't play by the rules.

sscanf() under CVI returns a -1 when only a partial match occurs, but it makes the partial matches.  It also does nothing with errno, which apparently, scanf functions are allowed to ignore.

So 'answer' is a non-compatible version of sscanf under CVI.

If anyone wants to post an answer, I will accept and credit it.

Comment: You should update your question to include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . Otherwise the possibility exists that you have got a bug somewhere in the code that you were running in CVI.

Comment: This is a MCVE with CVI.